# Ubuntu15.10 make a screenshot with keyboard shortcut no save option display？

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have to take a Screen-shot icon from left favorite bar to open a Copy to clipboard ----------- save window.
 When I was using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>print</kbd> shortcut in setting in the All Systems -> Keyboard, the window never show and the Picture directory have nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you are looking for the screen-shot shortcut its just <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> on your keyboard. Just press the button and gnome-screen-shot will open and ask you where to store the screen-shot.

If you want more advanced screen-shot options open Software Center and search for "shutter".

Comment: "alt prtsc" will capture only the active window.